# History mode in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using angularjs with history mode turned on and would want to make all links(all a's href) to load with history api... So, i have set

```
 $locationProvider.html5Mode(true)
```

And now the issue is that all pages reload the normal way. The url set in base tag is

```
  http://localhost:8080/laravel/public/
```

Comment: What do you mean by "all links to load with history api"? What do you mean by "all pages reload the normal way"? What behavior do you expect? What behavior do you get?

Comment: Like the twitter.com nav links, with html5 pushstate...

Answer (score 0):

Got it solved... So, i would have to do the routing. I had to add routes to load with history api...

Comment: Can you expand on that answer a bit perhaps please? It would be great if you could give enough details that someone else encountering the same problem can also understand it.